# Every term can be $\alpha-\text{converted}$ to a term without bound-variable clashes.

Tags: type-theory

This is a lemma in the book of basic simple type theory - Hindley.
But I am struggling to proof and also to understand this question.

Comment: You should really add some information about what work you've done on the question. For a hint: what can you say about the $\lambda$-terms $\lambda x.\lambda x.x$ and $\lambda y.\lambda x.x$?

Comment: But, I didn't even understand the question in itself.

Comment: Look at the two $\lambda$-terms in my comment: what can you say about the bound variables in those terms?

Comment: I am gonna trying to write down my answer as I am understanding. I will spend time, but, I intend to come back here and show you my answer, ok?